# NextJS Refreshing useeffect

Tags: javascript, next.js, jsx

I'm making a website with a list of services
When we click on a service, i open a service details page.
But the refreshing do not work well, i mix useEffect() + tantask query
And the query take time to refresh the UI.

```js
const session = useSession()
const path = usePathname()
const pathParts = path.split('/')
const slug = pathParts[pathParts.length - 1]
const [village, setVillage] = useState(session.data?.user.selectedVillage)
```

The query

```js
const fetchService = async () => {

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/api/villages/service/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ villageId: village?.id, slug: slug }),
            });

            const data = await response.json();
            const { service } = data;
            return { service: service }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error occured")
        }


        return { data: undefined }

    };

 const { isPending, data, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['detailsService', village?.id],
    queryFn: fetchService,
    enabled: !!village,  
});
```

And the useEffect() to refresh when slug change from URL

```js
  useEffect(() => {
        if (data && slug !== data.service.slug) {
            refetch(); 
        }
    }, [slug, data]); 
    
    if (isPending || !data) return <LoadingComponent />
```

The JSX part showing a title with a FORM, but the form take data.service with the same data when i change the service

```js
 return (
        <div className='flex flex-wrap'>
            <div className='h-screen w-[24rem] relative'>
                <Link href='/dashboard/services/' className='absolute ml-3 mt-3 text-white font-semibold' style={{ zIndex: 1 }}>RETOUR</Link>
                <img loading="lazy" className=" w-full h-full items-center bg-cover " style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${data.service.bannerImage})` }} />
                <div className='absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-darkgreen bg-opacity-70 flex justify-center items-center'>
                    <div className="max-w-sm bg-white rounded-xl shadow w-64 hover:shadow-xl">
                        <img loading="lazy" className="rounded-t-lg w-screen h-32 object-cover" src={data.service.bannerImage} alt={data.service.name} />
                        <div className="p-5 text-center flex flex-col items-center">
                            <h5 className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-[black]"> {data.service.name} </h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 flex justify-center mb-10'>
                    <UploadPhotoButton />    
                </div>
            </div>
            

            <div className='m-10' >
                <h2 className='text-3xl font-semibold'>Configurer {data.service.name}</h2>
                <div className="w-[36rem]">
                    <ServiceForm service={data.service} onUpdate={refetch} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

My questions are :

- What's the equivalent to useEffect ?
- Can we accelerate request ? with cache ?
- How to update the data.service when i change the service (the slug change but not the data)

Comment: You can avoid using useEffect by using Tanstack Query, don't combine them. Using axios instead of default fetch will make your life way more easier.